# Query in SVNKit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am using SVNKit to access a repository that contains binary files. I need to go to specific directories in the repository and retrieve a list of files from them. Then I do this:(sloppy code)

```
 Collection<SVNDirEntry> entries=(Collection<SVNDirEntry> repository.getDir(omitted);
 Iterator<SVNDirEntry> it=entries.iterator();
 while(it.hasNext()){
      SVNDirEntry entry=(SVNDirEntry) it.next();
      if(entry.getName().contains("abc")){
           list.add(entry.getName());
      }
 }
```

Most directories contain few files and I have no problem using getDir(....) from SVNRepository, but there is one folder that has about 10000 files(or more) and the application just comes to a stop when I try to do that. Even if I wait for hours nothing happens. Is there anyway to solve this? I don't really need all of the files, just the ones that contain a certain code in their filename. Could I ask the repository to only give me the filenames containing "abc" inorder to speed this up?

Btw, I know this isn't a good way to use Subversion but I am sadly forced to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably blowing up memory on your Collections statement.

Use the handler version of the `getDir` method:

```
getDir(String path, long revision, Map properties, ISVNDirEntryHandler handler)
```

That way, you're only processing one file at a time.

Comment: I tried doing like this:

     repository.getDir(path,headRevision,null,new ISVNDirEntryHandler(){
public void handleDirEntry(SVNDirEntry dirEntry){
if(dirEntry.getName().contains("abc")){
list.add(dirEntry.getName();
}});

And that works for directories with few files, but it still comes to an halt when there are many files. When I debug I notice that with big directories it doesn't it execute the lines in the handler. Seems like it doesn't process one at a time :(